# Split value from a data.frame and create additional row to store its component

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, dplyr

In R, I have a data frame called **df** such as the following:

**A**      **B**      **C**      **D** 
a1    b1    c1     2.5 
a2    b2    c2     3.5

a3    b3    c3     5 - 7 
a4    b4    c4     2.5

I want to split the value of the third row and **D** column by the dash and create another row for the second value retaining the other values for that row.

So I want this:

**A**      **B**      **C**      **D** 
a1    b1    c1     2.5 
a2    b2    c2     3.5

a3    b3    c3     5 

a3    b3    c3     7
a4    b4    c4     2.5

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Ideally, I would also want to create an extra column to specify whether the value I split is either a minimum or maximum.

So this:

**A**      **B**      **C**       **D**      **E** 
a1    b1    c1     2.5 
a2    b2    c2     3.5

a3    b3    c3     5      min

a3    b3    c3     7           max

a4    b4    c4     2.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use `sub` to paste 'min' and 'max in the 'D" column where `-` is found, and then use `cSplit` to split the 'D' column.

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1$D <- sub('(\\d+) - (\\d+)', '\\1,min - \\2,max', df1$D)
res <- cSplit(cSplit(df1, 'D', ' - ', 'long'), 'D', ',')[is.na(D_2), D_2 := '']
setnames(res, 4:5, LETTERS[4:5])
res
#   A  B  C   D   E
#1: a1 b1 c1 2.5    
#2: a2 b2 c2 3.5    
#3: a3 b3 c3 5.0 min
#4: a3 b3 c3 7.0 max
#5: a4 b4 c4 2.5
```

Comment: Related question: what if you have negative numbers in your starting data frame? Seems like a split on  "-" will cause problems for this situation. Thanks.

Comment: @pseudorandom  Try `df1$D <- sub('(-*\\d+) - (-*\\d+)', '\\1,min - \\2,max', df1$D)` (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyrish way:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(A,B,C) %>% 
  do(data.frame(D = as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(.$D), " - ")[[1]]))) %>% 
  mutate(E = if (n()==2) c("min","max") else "")


       A      B      C     D     E
  (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (chr)
1     a1     b1     c1   2.5      
2     a2     b2     c2   3.5      
3     a3     b3     c3   5.0   min
4     a3     b3     c3   7.0   max
5     a4     b4     c4   2.5
```

Dplyr has a policy against expanding rows, as far as I can tell, so the ugly

```
do(data.frame(... .$ ...))
```

construct is required. If you are open to data.table, it's arguably simpler here:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)[,{
  D = as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(D)," - ")[[1]])
  list(D = D, E = if (length(D)==2) c("min","max") else "")
}, by=.(A,B,C)]


    A  B  C   D   E
1: a1 b1 c1 2.5    
2: a2 b2 c2 3.5    
3: a3 b3 c3 5.0 min
4: a3 b3 c3 7.0 max
5: a4 b4 c4 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::separate_rows`. I altered the input to include a negative value to makeit more general :

```r
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text=
"A      B      C      D 
a1    b1    c1     -2.5 
a2    b2    c2     3.5 
a3    b3    c3     '5 - 7' 
a4    b4    c4     2.5")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(E="", E = replace(E, grepl("[^^]-",D), "min - max")) %>%
  separate_rows(D,E,sep = "[^^]-", convert = TRUE)
#>    A  B  C    D    E
#> 1 a1 b1 c1 -2.5     
#> 2 a2 b2 c2  3.5     
#> 3 a3 b3 c3  5.0  min
#> 4 a3 b3 c3  7.0  max
#> 5 a4 b4 c4  2.5
```